# How to disabled search on disabled option jquery select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

This is my example. There `my price` option that have been disabled. If i search using select2 it still came up as a result. What i want is, how to make disabled option didn't came up as a result ? In this case i dont want `my price` came up if i type `my` for example. Is it possible ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".selectvoc").select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectvoc" name="voucher">
<optgroup label="voc1">
<option>vocvoc1</option>
<option disabled>my price1</option>
<option>vocvoc2</option>
<option disabled>my price2</option> 
<option>vocvoc3</option>
<option disabled>my price3</option> 
<optgroup label="voc2">
<option>vocvoc1</option>
<option disabled>my price1</option>
<option>vocvoc2</option>
<option disabled>my price2</option> 
<option>vocvoc3</option>
<option disabled>my price3</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Gave a try with no success https://jsfiddle.net/gesoh8L0/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can include the css style for the disabled one's in your options so that when you are trying to search the disabled one's they wont come

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".selectvoc").select2();
    });
```

```css
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

    <script src=""></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <select class="selectvoc" name="voucher">
    <optgroup label="voc1">
    <option>vocvoc1</option>
    <option disabled hidden>my price1</option>
    <option>vocvoc2</option>
    <option disabled>my price2</option> 
    <option>vocvoc3</option>
    <option disabled>my price3</option> 
    <optgroup label="voc2">
    <option>vocvoc1</option>
    <option disabled>my price1</option>
    <option>vocvoc2</option>
    <option disabled>my price2</option> 
    <option>vocvoc3</option>
    <option disabled>my price3</option> 
    </select>
```

Comment: hmm it will display none, even if i didnt search it @Sandeep Bhaskar

Comment: the problem you got it with is searching if u search the disabled data also u will got it right so if you add display none then even if you search then it wont display for only disabled data